# Laravel giving error in foreach loop in spatie-permission

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-permission

I was applying Spatie Laravel-permissions and coding to add permissions to roles.
and faced a error.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
//Validate name and permissions field
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'=>'required|unique:'.config('permission.table_names.roles').'|max:10',
        ]
    );

    $name = $request['name'];
    $role = new Role();
    $role->name = $name;

    $permissions = $request['permissions'];
    $role->save();
//Looping thru selected permissions
    if(count($permissions>0)){
    foreach ($permissions as $permission) {

        $p = Permission::where('id', '=', $permission)->firstOrFail(); 
     //Fetch the newly created role and assign permission
        $role = Role::where('name', '=', $name)->first(); 
        $role->givePermissionTo($p);
    }
}

    return redirect()->route('roles.index')
        ->with('flash_message',
         'Role'. $role->name.' added!'); 
}
```

[image: Error Image]

So if someone please help me solve this problem.

Comment: `dd($request['permissions'])` - what you are getting?

Comment: i am getting "3" @SougataBose

Comment: the number '3' ?

Comment: yes sir @IjasAmeenudeen

Comment: So it is not an array.

Comment: Are you using input arrays? like `permissions[]` in form?

Comment: its a checkbox I am taking an input, no I am not using array @SougataBose

Comment: Use an array for permissions as @SougataBose mentioned. It will fix your issue.

Comment: thanks I will do that @IjasAmeenudeen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your submit form use this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="{{ $r->id }}"> {{$r->display_name}} </li>
```

In controller catch these permissions like this

```
$permissions = $request->permissions;
```